# Verify solution to $\frac{i R}{L}+i'=\frac{U_m \sin (\text{$\omega $t})}{L}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Show that this is a solution

$$i(t)\text{:=}\frac{U_m \sin (t \omega -\varphi )}{Z}$$

to

$$i'+\frac{i R}{L}=\frac{U_m \sin (t \varphi )}{L}$$

given:

$$\varphi =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{L$\omega $}}{R}\right)$$

$$Z=\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}$$

This is what I have done so far.

$$\frac{d\frac{U_m \sin (t \omega -\varphi )}{Z}}{dt}$$

$$\sin (\varphi )=\frac{L \omega }{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}$$

$$\cos (\varphi )=\frac{R}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}$$

$$\frac{U_m \sin (t \omega -\varphi )}{Z}=\frac{U_m (\cos (\varphi ) \sin (t \omega )-\sin (\varphi ) \cos (t \omega ))}{Z}=\frac{U_m \left(\frac{R \sin (t \omega )}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}-\frac{(L \omega ) \cos (t \omega )}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}\right)}{Z}=\frac{U_m (R \sin (t \omega )-L \omega  \cos (t \omega ))}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2} \sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}=\frac{U_m (R \sin (t \omega )-L \omega  \cos (t \omega ))}{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}$$

$$i'=\frac{\left(\omega  U_m\right) \cos (\varphi -t \omega )}{Z}=\frac{\left(\omega  U_m\right) (\sin (\varphi ) \sin (t \omega )+\cos (\varphi ) \cos (t \omega ))}{Z}=\frac{\left(\omega  U_m\right) \left(\frac{(L \omega ) \sin (t \omega )}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}+\frac{R \cos (t \omega )}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}}=\frac{\omega  U_m (L \omega  \sin (t \omega )+R \cos (t \omega ))}{L^2 \omega ^2+R^2}$$

Now Im stuck, how do I continue?

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know how to solve this equation, you could just differentiate the solution and use $\sin(a + b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b$.

Comment: @SimonS Could you now have a look at the expression to see where I have gone wrong and how to solve it?

Comment: I have to say I am not given any other information in the text book then what I have provided here.

Comment: Forget it I got it!